# Seat blocking next to Star Alliance elite flyers on Turkish Airlines

Tags: seating, star-alliance

I am trying to select an economy seat for my flight later today on Turkish Airlines. I am Turkish elite (SA Gold) and I had selected an aisle seat earlier and now I find the next two seats show as occupied.

There are other rows which are fully empty as well.

What I am trying to figure out is whether the "occupied" seats are truly occupied (in which case it makes sense for me to change my seat to an empty row) or whether Turkish seat allocation logic blocks a seat next to an elite status flyer until all other seats are filled (in which case I should stick to this seat and try my luck).

Anyone know if Turkish actually has seat logic which tries to block seats next to its Elite fliers?

Recently I flew long haul on Singapore Airlines and I was probably the only passenger with an empty row. But I will never know if that was pure luck or a perk of my Star Alliance gold status.

On this Turkish Airlines flight I still see about 10% seats empty.

Comment: Often are passengers which select the seats (and so maybe it is a group of five, or more) (and algorithms are not always well performing, like a good airline agents of the olden times). So, do not extrapolate from only one occurrence.